# Cypher: Matching multiple nodes not connected by path

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm having a problem using Neo4j at the moment where I want to match two ore more nodes, that are not connected by any path.

Let's say we have a graph with two context components (is this the right word?), for example 4 nodes `(A)-->(B)` and `(C)-->(D)`.

When I run `MATCH (A), (C)` in this situation, i get "No Rows" as result, probably because the algorithm can't reach `(C)` after having chosen `(A)` as starting node.

How can I still match those nodes?

Comment: Can you provide de Cypher statements that you are using to create your nodes?

Comment: `MATCH (A), (C)` should return a Cartesian product between all node pairs... can you create a MVCe in the Neo4j [console](http://console.neo4j.org/)  and share it?

Comment: "probably because the algorithm can't reach (C) after having chosen (A) as starting node." The query engines does not do a traversal, so it can reach nodes that are not connected.

Comment: If your query is something like `MATCH (A), (C) RETURN *`, and it returns no rows, then the only reasonable explanation is that your DB has no nodes. In that is true, then even `MATCH (A) RETURN *` should return no nodes.

Comment: I tried to recreate it by doing create `(a:A)-[:HAS]->(b:B), (c:C)-[:HAS]->(d:D)` and then querying `match (a:A),(c:C) return a,c`. However it worked. Yesterday I used Neo4j 3.1.0, today I'm using 3.2.2. I'll check it when I get back to my Neo4j 3.1.0

Comment: On the Neo4j 3.1.0 at home it still doesn't work.
I've installed a 3.1.0 on my work laptop and it works. Seems like the problem doesn't really comes from the Neo4j, so my native approach seems to be the correct one. I see this as answered until I know more about the real problem. Knowing this should work in theory is enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem is caused from something other than Neo4j.
I can't recreate it on another computer.
The approach to use `MATCH (A), (B)` was the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

I think you really want `MATCH (A) MATCH (C) ...` without the comma. This will give you two starting points which you can either `RETURN` or pass forward with `WITH`. As Tezra says, using the comma will create a cartesian product.

Comment: `MATCH (A) MATCH (C)` and `MATCH (A), (C)` are equivalent. Both will cause a cartesian product.

Comment: I stand corrrected. A simple `EXPLAIN MATCH(A) MATCH(C)` would have told me this - dooh!